# Is there a way to have a Resource name inside strings.xml with a space?

Tags: android, android-resources

Example:

Android complains that ' ' is not a valid resource name character.

Am I forced to use say "New_Delhi" and then programatically map this in my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for the simple reason that Java fields cannot have spaces in their names. A string resource named `New_Delhi` is referenced in Java as `R.string.New_Delhi`. A space, in lieu of the underscore, would not be valid Java syntax.