# How to access an image file from assets in Flutter that has spaces in it's name?

Tags: android, image, flutter, widget, assets

Working on a Flutter application project that has some absurd naming conventions from the design team which prepares image assets, therefore the following question.

What's the syntax to access an image file which has spaces in it's name? For example I have an image named *"United Arab Emirates.png"* residing in my assets path i.e *"assets/Flags/United Arab Emirates.png"* When I try to access this path in Image.asset() widget I am unable to load it because the image has spaces in it's name. If I remove the space I can load it and show it in the widget. The problem here is I can not rename a huge amount of images I have in my assets directory and don't know how to write a script to rename all the assets and don't want to invest time learning how to write a script.

There must be some syntax to access these assets as I think this is a pretty generic issue that should have happened with lot of people but I don't see any questions or answer posted regarding this.

Comment: What flutter version are you using? It's working on  stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9,

Comment: Related issue ticket: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55311

Comment: @MorrisonChang Your ticket link is not even remotely related to my question.

Comment: @Locked I am using (Channel beta, 1.20.0) but I also tried it on latest stable channel at the time of posting the question.

Comment: @TahaAli Based on the last comment in my issue ticket link, it seems to have worked at some point (based on this [issue with font names with spaces](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17578)). Double check by doing [flutter clean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52730971/295004) and rebuilding. If still a problem, either (a) file a issue ticket if you believe it to be a bug OR (b) conform to [Android resource file naming rules which doesn't allow for spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36483076/295004).

Answer (score 0):

I think flutter add assets to embed , like res/draw in android, not assets folder, so the filename can not include space or other unexpected chars